# Ggplot problem with coloring multiple points

Tags: r, ggplot2, categories, facet

well i have this data frame

```
   DateTime value  Name   Category Status    Type
1  2021-06-08    50  TEST TEST DESCR    HOT    <NA>
2  2021-06-08    55  TEST TEST DESCR   COLD    <NA>
3  2021-06-08    54  TEST TEST DESCR  HEAVY    <NA>
4  2021-06-08    58  TEST TEST DESCR    OLD    <NA>
5  2021-06-08    44  TEST TEST DESCR    HOT    <NA>
6  2021-06-08    53  TEST TEST DESCR    HOT    <NA>
7  2021-06-10    56  TEST TEST DESCR    OLD    <NA>
8  2021-06-10    58  TEST TEST DESCR    OLD    <NA>
9  2021-06-29    59  TEST TEST DESCR   COLD    <NA>
10 2021-06-29    60  TEST TEST DESCR   COLD    <NA>
11 2021-06-30    43  TEST TEST DESCR  HEAVY    <NA>
12 2021-06-30    45  TEST TEST DESCR  HEAVY    <NA>
13 2021-06-30    59  TEST TEST DESCR    HOT    <NA>
14 2021-06-08   100 TEST2     BEAUTY   <NA>   ERROR
15 2021-06-30     0 TEST2      UNGLY   <NA>   ERROR
16 2021-06-30   200 TEST2      FUGLY   <NA> WARNING
17 2021-06-10    70 TEST2       THIN   <NA> WARNING
18 2021-06-08    33 TEST2        FAT   <NA> WARNING
```

and i am using this code

```
ggplot(data = dummydata, mapping = aes(x = DateTime, y = value,group = 1,colour=Status))+
  geom_point(data=dummydata[dummydata$Name=="TEST",],shape=21,fill="black")+
  geom_path(data=dummydata[dummydata$Name=="TEST",])+
  
  facet_grid(Name~., scale = "free") +
  geom_point(data=dummydata[dummydata$Name!="TEST",], 
             aes(shape = factor(Category),fill=factor(Type)),size=2) + 
  labs(colour="Status",fill="Type",shape="Description")+
  labs(x = "Dates",y="Values") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
    angle = 90,
    vjust = 1,
    hjust = 1
  ))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)))
```

which results on this output

[image]

Does anyone know why my points on TEST2 are not colored based on type?
Can I make those points red for error and blue for warning?

Comment: For `geom_point`, you can only use the `fill` aesthetic if you use a point type that supports it, such as `shape = 21`.

Comment: Okk but how can i color the shapes according to if it is error or warning?